# TypeError: "HTMLElement constructor: 'new' is required"

Tags: javascript

I have got some issue with stackblitz, given me an error:

```
TypeError: "HTMLElement constructor: 'new' is required".
```

The strange thing about it is that VS Code runs the same code perfect but unfortunately I need to submit my assignment with stackblitz link so for doing that i need to fix the errors..

```js
class myStudent extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super()

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    let sID = this.getAttribute("student-id")
    let studentItem;
    for (let i = 0; i < mystudents.length; i++) {
      if (mystudents[i].stuID == sID) {
        studentItem = mystudents[i]
        break;
      }
    }

    let name = document.createElement("b")
    name.innerHTML = "Name: " + studentItem.Name + "<br>"
    shadowRoot.appendChild(name)

    let age = document.createElement("span")
    age.innerHTML = "Age: " + studentItem.Age + "<br>"
    shadowRoot.appendChild(age)

    let year = document.createElement("span")
    year.innerHTML = "Year: " + studentItem.Year + "<br>"
    shadowRoot.appendChild(year)

    let excep = document.createElement("span")
    excep.innerHTML = "Exceptional: " + studentItem.Exceptional + "<br>"
    shadowRoot.appendChild(excep)

    let br = document.createElement("br")
    shadowRoot.appendChild(br)
  }
}

customElements.define('my-student', myStudent);
```

Thank you all in advance : )

Comment: Are you sure you're using exactly this code and not something like `customElements.define('my-student', myStudent());`. The error message implies that you've used `myStudent()` somewhere in the code.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges Yes i tried, does not work ...

Comment: @Titus Yes this is the code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/exercise3, that's the link with all of the files from stackblitz.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges It was not like that, i'm trying right now many variations.

Comment: It seems that the problem is how `stackblitz` transpiles your code. It changes `class` definitions to normal `functions`.

Comment: @Titus And by you opinion there is nothing to do with it ? Try to submit it with VS Code html file and that's it ?

Comment: @Guillaume Georges: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define - it's a browser API to create custom elements

Comment: You can use another website, JSBin for example https://jsbin.com/werixokehe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Stackblitz uses Babel to transpile your code to ES5, but that turns your class constructor into a regular function and that clashes with the browser's expectations.

See https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/475. You can also find the solution there (which is a workaround for the time being):

> As a workaround, you can add this shim to the external resources list: `https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js`

Alternatively you can try adding `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs` as a dependency and then importing the shim manually before any of your other code:

```js
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js'
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js'
```

Comment: Thank you ! and where is that external resource list ?

Comment: In the sidebar you should be able to add it as a dependency.

Comment: You can also try the way it was done here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/customelements